# get distinct values as array by user_id

Tags: mysql

I want to get a list of distinct values for each user limited by 3 values per user:

id, user_id, value

```
1, 1, a
2, 1, b
3, 2, c
4, 1, b
5, 1, d
6, 1, e
```

expected result:

```
user_id, values
1, [a,b,d]
2, [c]
```

is there some way to do this with `GROUP BY user_id` and `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Are you sure the expected result for 1 shouldn't be `1, [a,b,d]`?

Comment: @GaryThomas infact `[a,b,d,e]`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya "limited by 3 values per user"

Comment: "limited by 3 values per user"

Comment: @GaryThomas thanks for the hint. I changed it

Answer (score 1):

**Edit ([based on comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396509/get-distinct-values-as-array-by-user-id/53396543?noredirect=1#comment93669738_53396543)):**

We can use user-defined variables to assign row number to various `value` within a partition of `user_id`. Eventually, we will filter out this result-set to consider upto 3 rows per `user_id` only.

```
SELECT 
  dt2.user_id, 
  dt2.value 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    @rn := CASE WHEN @ui = dt.user_id THEN @rn + 1
                ELSE 1
           END AS row_no, 
    @ui = dt.user_id, 
    dt.value 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      user_id, 
      value
    FROM your_table
    ORDER BY user_id 
  ) AS dt 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @ui := null) AS user_init_vars 
) AS dt2 
WHERE dt2.row_no <= 3
```

---

**Previous question's answer:**

- [`Group_Concat(Distinct...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) all the unique `value` for a `user_id`.
- We can then use [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to consider string upto 3rd comma. This will then result in consideration of upto 3 values only.
- At the end, we can use [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to enclose the resultant string in square brackets.
- `Values` is [Reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-V). You can consider naming the resultant column into something else.

Try the following:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       CONCAT('[', 
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value), ',', 3), 
              ']') AS user_values 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately it performs poorly, since GROUP_CONCAT retrieves all values and the distinct values potentially contain millions of entries. I would therefore prefer a query where I can apply a limit to instead of using substring.

Comment: It would also be ok if the result is not an array, but separate rows with a single distinct value each

Comment: @Chris do you have access to latest MySQL server version ? Can you use 8.0.2 and above ?

Comment: I use Azure for hosting. So I am stuck with 5.7